# Pip Install File Exiting with Exit Status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, pip, pycharm

I'm trying to install `file` module in order to perform some operations. I tried this on PyCharm as well CMD using the command: `pip install file`. But I'm stuck at this long error message:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\Bogota\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Bogota\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-install-lkio_gqw\\file\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Bogota\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-install-lkio_gqw\\file\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Bogota\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-record-wmjnd524\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\Bogota\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\file'
         cwd: C:\Users\Bogota\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-lkio_gqw\file\
    Complete output (32 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\file
    copying src\file\_libmagic_build.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\file
    copying src\file\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\file
    running egg_info
    writing src\file.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\file.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to src\file.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to src\file.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\file.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[cod]' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dylib' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'src\file.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win-amd64-3.7\\Release\\file._libmagic.c'
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    building 'file._libmagic' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\Bogota\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\Bogota\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcbuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\file._libmagic.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\file._libmagic.obj
    file._libmagic.c
    build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\file._libmagic.c(540): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'magic.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\Bogota\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Bogota\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-install-lkio_gqw\\file\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Bogota\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-install-lkio_gqw\\file\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Bogota\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-record-wmjnd524\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\Bogota\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\file' Check the logs for full command output.
```

In this error message, it has mentioned that I don't have `magic.h` in any directory. Later I installed this using `pip install libmagic` but the error is not resolved still.

What could be the possible mistake am I making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: While I was looking to open a file and read the data in bytes format, I came across this `file` module. But unfortunately, this module is not available in Python 3. So if you want to read the data of a file in bytes, you can simply open the file in binary read format i.e. `'rb'` and use `.read()` after file name.

For example:
            `open('ABC.cer', 'rb').read()`